# Find the list of immediate next directory from the given location for reaching a destination file?

Tags: command-line, find, paths

We can find the full absolute path of a destination file using *find* keyword. In my case, I need the list of all immediate next directory to my given location which can lead me to my program log file named *foo.log*

For example, some of the paths may be:

```
given-location/alpha/beta/gamma/foo.log
given-location/apple/banana/foo.log
```

For the above case, I need a list/array/vector anything like `['alpha', 'apple']` as my result as it contains all the possible immediate next folder to reach the destination file.

I'm new to *Linux* tools. I know, I can always create a brute force solution as I have the absolute-path as well as the given-path, but any optimized/better solution or any hint/idea in the right direction will do!

I don't want the first distinct folder, just the immediate folder to the given-location.

My brute force approach:

```
result={}
   for all the Absolute-path which can reach foo.log:
       Suffix-path = (Absolute-path - given-path)
       Append the Suffix-path[0] to result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%P` format directive will give you the path directly after the *starting-point*:

```bsh
find given-location/ -type f \
  -name 'foo.log' -printf %P\\n | cut -f1 -d /
```

You can append the output from `find` to an array using the `+=` operator:

```bsh
a=(); a+=( \
  $(find given-location/ -type f \
       -name 'foo.log' -printf %P\\n | cut -f1 -d / \
  ) \
); echo "${a[@]}"
```

The next example makes use of globstar `**/`; matches zero or many subdirectories.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob
a=()
for b in given-location/**/foo.log; do
    readarray -t -d / -s 1 -n 1 -O ${#a[@]} a <<< "$b"
done
echo "${a[@]}"
```

Moving the start index with `-O` to the end of the array makes it possible to append new values.

- `-t` Remove a trailing delim
- `-d` Delim is used to terminate each input line, rather than newline.
- `-s` Discard the first count lines read.
- `-n` Copy at most count lines.
- `-O` Begin assigning to array at index origin.

Comment: Hi, please look at this one too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316533/whats-the-replacement-of-find-command-of-unix-using-python-pathlib-api

Answer (score 1):

Get second field of a string with awk:

```
$ echo 'given-location/alpha/beta/gamma/foo.log' | awk -F/ '{print $2}'
alpha

awk command options used
-F/ : specify '/' as fields separator char
$2  : second field
```

Comment: Think he wants the second field from the beginning.

Comment: @bac0n : oops, tks. Edited !